# regex to remove everything after a certain character (comment)

Tags: c#, regex, line, character

I have a regex which I am using to remove everything after a specific character, semi-colon.

```
        var regex = new Regex(@";(.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        tb.Text = regex.Replace(tb.Text, "");
```

It seems to work fine, but at times it removes the entire text of the text box. For example all of this code is removed:

```
;fgkdfgdfgd
;dfgdfkghdfgdf
;sdgfsdfsdfsdf
;dfgdfgdfg

#dont remove this          ;fgdfgdfg
```

the "#dont remove this" should stay intact because it isn't after the semi-colon, but it doesn't? Is something wrong with my regex?

The idea is to remove or trim all comments from a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try (UPDATE after comment):

```
tb.Lines = (
    from l in tb.Lines 
    let x = l.IndexOf (';') 
    select (x >= 0 ? l.SubString (0, x) : l)
).ToArray();
```

This should run faster than the Regex too...

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but the goal of StackOverflow is to answer the question.  Providing alternative solutions is only secondary, and should only be used to make good answers better.

Comment: @Scott Rippey I don't get where you gather that. Sometimes offering a simpler, more efficient solution is absolutely the way to go. Many people learning new skills attempt solving every problem with that new skill, it's not outside of the scope of SO to steer people in the right direction. Just let the code do the majority of the talking, so that's it's tangible stuff and not just words...

Comment: @John Leidegren: when I have a programming question, I look for others who have asked something similar. If their accepted answer is "do it a different way", that's about as helpful as "never mind, fixed it". SO is more about finding answers than asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using `RegexOptions.Singleline` and therefore the `.` is matching new lines.

Answer (score 2):

`RegexOptions.Singleline` doesn't limit the match to a single line as you might expect.  In fact, its purpose is just the opposite.  It allows the `.` metacharacter to match newlines, making it *easier* to find matches that span across multiple lines.  Just drop that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very simple - you misunderstood `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

`SingleLine` tells the pattern that `.` can match line breaks.  [Read more about `RegexOptions` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

Your current result is a single match (from the first `;` to the end of the entire string).

You should just remove the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` and  your pattern will match each comment to the end of the line.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes I got confused between both SingleLine and MultiLine. Also, how would I remove all lines that start with the comment?

Comment: `MultiLine` isn't necessary -- it changes the meaning of `^` and `$`.  Your current pattern will work fine to clear lines that start with a comment -- but if you want to REMOVE lines that begin with a comment, that's for another question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily using this:

```
tb.Text = tb.Text.Substring(0, tb.Text.IndexOf(';'));
```

This should run faster than using Regex...

If your textbox is multiline you could use:

```
s = TextBox1.Text;
string ret = "";
s.Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(p=>ret += p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf(';')) + "\n");
TextBox1.Text = ret;
```

Comment: that would produce the same empty result!

Comment: @Yahia: I've just tried it to be sure and _"#dont remove this"_ string remains...